# Hbase installation in three node hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have installed my hadoop three node cluster(master,slave1 and slave2).
I would like to install Hbase fully distrubuted mode. I am think to install HBase Master and Zookeepr in my hadoop cluster MASTER machine(i.e Namenode), And Region Servers in SLAVE1 and SLAVE2(i.e Datanodes) machines. Is this correct approach ?

Sorry, This may be simple question but I am new to NoSQL systems and want to do this installations.

I really appreciate If someone able to share any reference document for ths installation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In order to configure hbase and zookeeper on three nodes, i.e., `1 master` and `2 slave` nodes, you will need to edit `hbase-site.xml, regionservers, hbase-env.sh` (found in `$HBASE_HOME/conf`) and `zoo.cfg` (found in `$ZOOKEEPER_HOME/conf`).

Let us name your master node as `master` and slave nodes as `slave1` and `slave2`. Let us consider your hadoop, hbase and zoopeeper folders are in `/usr/local/cluster/` folder. Change the following files:

**1. hbase-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.master</name>
    <value>master:60000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://master:8020/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>slave1,slave2</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/usr/local/cluster/zk-tmp</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**2. hbase-env.sh:**

--add these lines--

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
export HBASE_HOME=/usr/local/cluster/hbase
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/cluster/hadoop
```

--modify these lines--

```
export HBASE_PID_DIR=/usr/local/cluster/zk-tmp
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false
```

**3. regionservers:**

(delete the localhost and add these lines if you just want your regionservers in `slave1` and `slave2` only)

```
slave1
slave2
```

**4. zoo.cfg:**

--modify these lines--

```
dataDir=/usr/local/cluster/zk-tmp
```

--add these lines(since you start zookeeper server on master node)--

```
server.0=master:2888:3888
```

**5. etc/hosts:**

Edit the `/etc/hosts` file and comment the line with `127.0.1.1` (to avoid loopback address problems)

--add these lines--

```
your-master-node-ip master
your-slave1-node-ip slave1
your-slave2-node-ip slave2
```

**Note: Do steps 1 to 5 in master, slave1 and slave2 nodes.**

**6. Start zookeeper server in `master` node:**

```
$ZOOKEEPER_HOME/bin/zkServer.sh start
```

**7. Start hbase processes in `master` node:**

```
$HBASE_HOME/bin/start-hbase.sh
```

**8. Check your hbase and zookeeper processes:** Results for `jps` command in each node should contain-

--master--

```
QuorumPeerMain
HMaster
HRegionServer
```

--slave1--

```
HRegionServer
```

--slave2--

```
HRegionServer
```

**9. Stopping zookeeeper and hbase:**

```
$ZOOKEEPER_HOME/bin/zkServer.sh start
$HBASE_HOME/bin/stop-hbase.sh
```